# How can you make a header hide on scroll down, and appear on scroll up 5x (like google+)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, header

I'm trying to make my top navigation bar disappear after scrolling down at least 5px, and reappear after scrolling up 5px fast.  Very similar to google+ header.  I've tried searching for any tutorials, and I've tried some js and jQuery methods but I can't seem to get them to work.  View at [My Site](http://chitt-chat.com).

HTML:

```
<body>
   <div class="gridContainer clearfix">
      <nav id="topNav" class="fluid">
             <ul class="fluid fluidList navSystem">
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Web">Web</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Photos">Photos</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Videos">Videos</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Music">Music</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="People">People</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Places">Places</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="Shopping">Shopping</a></li>
                <li class="fluid navItem"><a href="#" title="More">More...</a></li>
        </ul> 
          </nav> <!-- END #topNav -->

          <header id="header" class="fluid">
          </header> <!-- END header -->      
      </div> <!-- END .gridContainer -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.gridContainer {
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 100%;
   clear: none;
   float: none;
}

#topNav {     
   overflow: hidden; 
   width: 100%;
   height: 29px;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: #2D2D2D;
   z-index: 999; 
}

#header {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 44px;
   position: fixed;
   background-color: #D2D2D2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Didn't look too deep into how it was implemented on their end. You could use a combination of tracking the scroll position and rendering changes from there with js:

```
var scroll_pos = 0;
var scroll_time;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(scroll_time);
    var current_scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (current_scroll >= $('#topNav').outerHeight()) {
        if (current_scroll <= scroll_pos) {
            $('#topNav').removeClass('hidden');    
        }
        else {
            $('#topNav').addClass('hidden');  
        }
    }

    scroll_time = setTimeout(function() {
        scroll_pos = $(window).scrollTop();
    }, 100);
});
```

And you'll have to add css class:

```
#topNav.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/frZ9j/

Comment: That works really well, thats 90% of what I need.  I still would like it to only appear on scroll up if the user scrolls really fast, if they scroll normal or slow I want the navigation to stay hidden.  Is that possible?

Comment: Another problem...  I've added a header at the bottom of my navigation as you can see at chitt-chat.com.  The header is covered by the navigation, I want it to be under the navigation and move up when the nav goes hidden.  I can post code and CSS for header if needed?

Comment: Ya that would be great.

Comment: In that case you may want to add some transition and do some animations like this: http://jsfiddle.net/frZ9j/1/ - I'm not familiar with anyway to detect scroll speed so I can't help you in that area.

Comment: Okay, that works really good.  It says not to say thank you, but oh well, thank you a lot, haha. @jerrylow

Comment: Will please look at chitt-chat.com there is a problem with the navigation :(

Comment: Ugh... haha, there actually is a problem.  Both the header and the navigation are hiding...

Comment: Oh, the boiler plate you're using has .hidden as something else, you can change the class I used to anything else and it should work.

Comment: Just came across this question. I wrote a little widget that solves this exact problem. Allows you to do things to elements on scroll up/down, have a tolerance for amount of scroll before it triggers a change (e.g. must have moved > 5 px), and have an offset before it is triggered (e.g. must be > 200px from top). You can find it here if you're interested: http://wicky.nillia.ms/headroom.js/